# Internet Explorer misinterprets html tags

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer misinterprets website: it reads `<tag></tag>`bla bla`</tag><//tag>` instead of `<tag>bla bla</tag>`. For instance the code of the nav section is:

```
   <nav>
   <ol>
   <li><form action="Algemene Voorwaarden Bijles Studio.pdf" method="get"   target="_blank">
   <button>algemene voorwaarden</button>
   </form>
   Bla Bla
   </li>
   </ol>
   </nav>
```

But the inspect element function of IE shows the following:

```
   <nav></nav>
   <ol>...</ol>
   </nav><//nav>
```

And this doesn't only happen with the nav tags, it also happens with figcaption, section, footer and other tags, for instance the IE inspect element shows:

```
  <figcaption></figcaption>
  Onze bijlesdocenten
  </figcaption><//figcaption>
```

Furthermore the website works fine in Google Chrome and other browsers.

The url of the site is: http://www.bijlesstudio.com
Comment: I asked this question on ProWebmasters, but they send me here because the mod thought it was an CSS problem, so don't delete this post for being a duplicate s.v.p.

Regards,
Jens Wagemaker

Comment: what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Version: 11.0.9600.17801

Comment: Doesn’t happen in my IE 11, the `nav` encompasses the `ol`, as to be expected. Only when I explicitly tell it to render in IE 8 mode, I see what you described. On a side note: Making every single navigation point into an individual form, only so you can use `button` elements to navigate, seems rather nonsense. You should rather use simple `a` links, and format them via CSS to _look_ like the buttons you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>One thing that can be happening is that</s> you are using Internet Explorer in 
**IE8 or older document mode which do not support the new semantic elements of HTML5.**

[image]

**[Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)**

---

### **To resolve:**

- check and change the document mode to IE9+ by `right-cliking` on the page->`inspect element`->(look around the right top corner in the inspect elemnt section) `select Edge` from dropdown.
  [image]

### **OR**

- you can add this to your pages `<head>...</head>` section

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  ```

  as common sense would tell, *this is a much better option* than the previous one.

Comment: When I do as u say, the website looks fine, so thanks a lot! I'm now going to add the code you suggested. I see that I already have `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />` on my page. Do I have to add the code u suggested below it, or do I have to replace it?

Comment: you are welcome! IE8 is used by very small percentage of people so you shouldn't worry about it much. Please do remember to accept this as an answer :-p.

Comment: Add below (or above) that line. There can be multiple `<meta>` tags in a html document, all have different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space `<ol >` which might be part of it but your editor is inserting a few Byte-Order-Marks which may be messing with IE. Check your editor's settings to turn that off.

Always [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.bijlesstudio.com/) to find such things.

Comment: I have deleted the space in the <ol> tag.

Comment: `<ol >` is perfectly valid HTML, even with the space.

Comment: @CBroe Yes but we're dealing with IE here which is like adjusting a rabbit ear antenna on your TV.

Comment: @Rob I will validate my next website :)